# Finding the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} P_0^n$ for a European Cash-or-Nothing put option with $P=K^2\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{S_T < K\}}$

Tags: finance-mathematics, probability, martingale, limits-to-arbitrage

**Exercise :**

> Let $K>0$. A European Cash-or-Nothing put option $P$ has the following pay-out profile :
>   $$P=K^2\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{S_T < K\}}$$
>   Let $P_0^n$ be the no-arbitrage value at time $0$ and the $n$-th binomial model. Calculate the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} P_0^n$. You can use fact that the random variable $S_T^n$ follows the log-normal distribution when $n \to \infty$ and that 
>   $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{1}_{\{S_T < K\}}] = \Phi(-d_2)$.

**Note :** For the binomial models, it is :
$$S_T^n = \prod_{i=1}^n(1+R_i^n)$$

**Question :**

Now, I know how one shows what the limit of $P_0^n$ is when simply $P=K$, but I am really struggling to manipulate the case of this special given $P$. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think a good starting point would be to use the Monotone Convergence Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem

Comment: @FunnyBuzer Hi. I don't know how to use the $P$ given. It's not standard as when we say it pays off $K$. Can you help me with the initial expression of $P_0^n$ ?

Comment: Not sure I understand you comment. You do know how to solve it when the payoff is $K \mathrm{1} \left\{ S_T < K \right\}$ and struggle with it being $K^2$?

Comment: @LocalVolatility Yes. We proved the limit of $P_0^n$ at class when the payoff is simply $K$ by using the expected martingale value of $(K-S_T)^+$ and expanding using the Triangular Central Limit Theorem, followed by the definition integrals and leading to the expressions involving $d_1$ and $d_2$. But, how would $K^2$ change that ? Would it just be the same but with $(K^2-S_T)^+$ ?

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things. An option that pays $K^2 \mathrm{1} \left\{ S_T < K \right\}$ has expected payoff which is just $K$ times that of an option that pays $K \mathrm{1} \left\{ S_T < K \right\}$. It is just a constant that you can take out of the expectation. Also, I don't see why your starting point is the call payoff as opposed to just the payoff the product you are interested in.

Comment: @LocalVolatility So that essentialy means that the limit will be $K \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} P_0^n$ where that limit in the expression is the one of payoff $K$ ?

Comment: Yes - that's right.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure I understand your question.  In the limit as n goes to infinity, the binomial price approaches the continuous price.   Your answer is simply k * N(-d2) where N(.) is the CDF of a standard normal with parameters given by a standard put option in BS framework